# why C++ template function do not support returning a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a function like this:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

// function to generate and retrun random numbers.
template<typename T>
T * getRandom( ) {
   static T  r[10];


   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      r[i] = 111;
      cout << r[i] << endl;
   }

   return r;
}

// main function to call above defined function.
int main () {
   // a pointer to an int.
   int *p;

   p = getRandom();
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      cout << "*(p + " << i << ") : ";
      cout << *(p + i) << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile the code using g++5.4 and c++11. The compiler gives me this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:18: error: no matching function for call to 'getRandom()'
    p = getRandom();
                  ^
main.cpp:25:18: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:8:5: note: template<class T> T* getRandom()
 T * getRandom( ) {
     ^
main.cpp:8:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:25:18: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
    p = getRandom();
              ^
```

It seems that C++ does not support to return a pointer that point to a template?

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with my toy example, thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to provide the type argument, as the error says it cannot deduce it from what you've given. `p = getRandom<int>();`

Comment: `auto *p = getRandom<int>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template parameter can't be [deduced](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from return type, but only from function arguments. So you have to specify the template argument explicitly. e.g.

```
p = getRandom<int>();
//           ~~~~~
```